# How prevent CSRF injection (special case - between 2 domains)

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, csrf

I have so situation.
We developed functionality on subdomain my.test.com.
And we have javascript on domain test.com, which must get data from my.test.com.

I realize its through proxy php file on test.com (i know about javascript library cross domain, but it simple).
This file connect to my.test.com and get necessary information.

But i think that may be CSRF injection.
How correct prevent CSRF inejction, when i connect from test.com throgh AJAX to proxy.php and next connect to test.com through php.

CSRF protection on my.test.com already implemented.

Comment: If proxy.php is on test.com and that's the scope of your ajax then why can't you just use a standard anti-CSRF token within a session on test.com?

Comment: @ MrCode
I don't have access to site.com - i only set proxy.php script to customer - and customer put this script on server and i can only send to proxy.php ajax request from one page.

Maybe that variant, but i'm not sure, that it safe.
When user go to page on site.com - i make ajax request - next save this token to page through javascript, and when visitor make another thing - i send data with that csrf and verify it.